# How to install java.pkg (not unarchiver)

Tags: macos

When I try to launch MC it says I have to have the latest java (OSX Yosemite)
this is the day after I updated.

So I download it, open the `dmg` and then to find out that it is not a `jar` launcher file (btw I know where it is located and how to use `jar` launcher). It is a `.pkg` that opens with the unarchiver.

I have read a previous post where it says that you need to launch it with `jar` launcer... I tried that, but it was a fail.

It said it can't be opened with `jar` launcher and then I get a console error message. So if anyone has a solution any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

The Java installer is a package which installs using Installer. If the package doesn't open by default with Installer then right-click it and choose Open With → Installer.